# Storing radio button value in session and retrieve (Radio button should be checked after retrieving) in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, radio-button

I am fetching 10 quiz question each having four different options from database..displaying those data using pagination one at a time with 4 options..now when i switch after answering first question and go back to previous one I found radio button gets unchecked..I want it should be checked.

Using Session for it but not getting it.
I am new to codeigniter.

Controller File

```
$newdata = array(
    'ques1' => $this->input->post('quizid1'),
         'ques2' => $this->input->post('quizid2'),
         'ques3' => $this->input->post('quizid3'),
         'ques4' => $this->input->post('quizid4'),
         'ques5' => $this->input->post('quizid5'),
         'ques6' => $this->input->post('quizid6'),
         'ques7' => $this->input->post('quizid7'),
         'ques8' => $this->input->post('quizid8'),
         'ques9' => $this->input->post('quizid9'),
         'ques10' => $this->input->post('quizid10'),
);

$this->session->set_userdata('newdata');
```

View File Code

```
<?php    
 $checked_value = $this->session->userdata('newdata');
?>

<input type="radio" name="quizid<?=$row->quizID?>" value="<?=$ans_array[0]?
>" <?=($checked_value == 0) ? 'checked="checked"' :'' ?>>  <?php echo 
"$ans_array[0]</br>"; ?> 

<input type="radio" name="quizid<?=$row->quizID?>" value="<?=$ans_array[1]?
>" <?=($checked_value == 1) ? 'checked="checked"' :'' ?>>  <?php echo 
"$ans_array[1]</br>"; ?> 

<input type="radio" name="quizid<?=$row->quizID?>" value="<?=$ans_array[2]?
>" <?=($checked_value == 2) ? 'checked="checked"' :'' ?>>  <?php echo 
"$ans_array[2]</br>"; ?> 

<input type="radio" name="quizid<?=$row->quizID?>" value="<?=$ans_array[3]?
>" <?=($checked_value == 3) ? 'checked="checked"' :'' ?>>  <?php echo 
"$ans_array[3]</br>"; ?>
```

Please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: print_r($checked_value), it will give multiple values as an array..but during checking you haven't pass the $checked_value[$quizid]. instead of that you are passing the whole session array.

Answer (score 0):

It should work, **whole session array** was used to check previously,instead of particular question's value..

```
  <input type="radio" name="quizid<?=$row->quizID?>" value="<?=$ans_array[0]?
    >" <?=($checked_value['ques'.$row->quizID] == 0) ? 'checked="checked"' :'' ?>>  <?php echo 
    "$ans_array[0]</br>"; ?> 

    <input type="radio" name="quizid<?=$row->quizID?>" value="<?=$ans_array[1]?
    >" <?=($checked_value['ques'.$row->quizID] == 1) ? 'checked="checked"' :'' ?>>  <?php echo 
    "$ans_array[1]</br>"; ?> 

    <input type="radio" name="quizid<?=$row->quizID?>" value="<?=$ans_array[2]?
    >" <?=($checked_value['ques'.$row->quizID] == 2) ? 'checked="checked"' :'' ?>>  <?php echo 
    "$ans_array[2]</br>"; ?> 

    <input type="radio" name="quizid<?=$row->quizID?>" value="<?=$ans_array[3]?
    >" <?=($checked_value['ques'.$row->quizID] == 3) ? 'checked="checked"' :'' ?>>  <?php echo 
    "$ans_array[3]</br>"; ?>
```